# Quero copiar para outro dataframe as informações das Linhas nas colunas X e Y quando as celulas abaixo na coluna X e Y estão vazias

Tags: python, microsoft-excel, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

Tenho uma planilha excel que estou usando como **dataframe**, ela contem os dados de assinaturas de clientes em colunas:

| CLIENTE | NUCLIENTE | NUASSINATURA | NUASSANTERIOR | DTEMISSAO - Dia-mês | VLASSINATURA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

Nessa planilha existe muitos clientes que possuem duas assinaturas em seu nome, eu preciso isolar os dados desses clientes específicos e passar para outra planilha.

Na planilha esses clientes com assinatura extras estão com uma **celula em branco** abaixo das colunas **"CLIENTE"**, na qual possuem seus respectivos nomes, e **"NUCLIENTE"** no qual contam com seus `ID`. Isso acontece pois **nome** e o `ID` desses clientes serem os mesmos e não ter necessidade de repeti-los duas vezes. **Exemplo:**

| CLIENTE | NUCLIENTE | NUASSINATURA |
| --- | --- | --- |
| YOSSEF KABACZNIK | 112038 | 123999 |
|  |  | 134179 |
| YUKUKO TSUCHIYA MASUDA | 143400 | 131745 |
| YURI ANDERSON | 203486 | 123837 |
| YURI ANDRE BRAGA MARQUES | 251495 | 131440 |

Na tabela acima o cliente **YOSSEF** está com uma assinatura extra no seu nome.

Utilizando `pandas` eu consegui criar um novo `dataframe` com os dados dos clientes filtrando a coluna **NUCLIENTE** para me trazer somente as celulas `empty` , o problema é que dessa forma eu não consigo os nomes dos clientes que estão na coluna **CLIENTE** e nem seus `ID` pois está sendo filtrado pelas celulas vazias dessa coluna.

Eu fiz isso da seguinte forma:

```
df = pd.read_excel("BASE ASSINATURAS EM ABERTO-novo.xlsx")
df = df.replace({"(vazio)":np.nan})
display(df)
print (df.info())
print(df.isna().sum())

nuclienteVazio = df[df['NUCLIENTE'].isnull()]
nuclienteVazio.to_excel("assinaturas_duplicadas.xlsx", sheet_name='planilha1', header = True)
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda para saber como consigo além das informações da assinatura dos **clientes**, seus nomes e `ID`.

Answer (score 1):

1 - Você pode ler o dataframe normalmente em um df

2 - Posteriormente você pode utilizar o método

```
df = df.fillna(method="bfill")
```

Você pode verificar os outros parâmetros necessário na documentação [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), mas já explico sobre o `method="bfill"`: o método irá varrer o dataframe a partir do tipo buscando pelos campos vazios. Ao encontrar, com este parâmetro `bfill` ele irá preenchê-lo com o valor da célula logo acima (`backfill`). Ou seja, as células ficarão com CLIENTES e NUCLIENTES duplicados.

3 - No dataframe resultante você pode aplicar o método

```
df[df.duplicated(subset=["CLIENTES", "NUCLIENTES"], keep=False)]
```

Documentação [aqui](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

Em resumo o df.duplicated irá criar uma mascara de True/False sobre os campos duplicados (com subset, ele irá olhar apenas para duplicados em CLIENTES E NUCLIENTES). O parametro *keep=False* fará com que ele retorne True para **todos** os duplicados (você tem outras opções que fazem filtros). Ao obter essa máscara e passar ela dentro de um df[], significa que você quer o df selecionando apenas os campos que retornaram True.

Por fim, você terá um dataframe com todos os campos preenchidos, somente das pessoas com mais de uma conta.

Em resumo:

```
df = pd.read_excel("BASE ASSINATURAS EM ABERTO-novo.xlsx")
df = df.fillna(method="bfill")
df_final = [df.duplicated(subset=["CLIENTES", "NUCLIENTES"], keep=False)]
```